# How to split the large dataframe based on a single value, 1130.07

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This data frame contains several different data set. They were all merged into one big dataframe and I want to split them into different columns based on the intensity value of 1130.07.

Example of the dataframe looks like this:

```
    intensity   wavelength
0   192.94  685.00
1   193.21  685.00
2   193.48  685.00
3   193.76  680.00
4   194.03  706.00
... ... ...
145915  1129.10 701.00
145916  1129.34 699.00
145917  1129.59 684.00
145918  1129.83 696.00
145919  1130.07 700.00
```

Comment: Do you want to split to less than 1130.07 and over 1130.07? Are you certain that count of rows is the same?

Comment: Split at 1130.07, and yup. the rows are all consistent!

Answer (score 2):

First create a boolean mask `m` and then assign two new dataframes based on this mask:

```
m = df.intensity < 1130.07
df1 = df[m]
df2 = df[~m]
```